Optimizing Background Images In Nuxt 3
I'm developing a Nuxt.js application and I need to set a decorative background image for a <div>. I prefer using background-image for decorative elements, as it is semantically more appropriate, while using <img> tags for content images. <NuxtImg> results in an optimized <img>, but I would like to optimize background-images.

You can use the useImage() to generate a helper function as described in the documentation
This will allow you to get an optimized image generation same way as NuxtImg tag, but returning just the url.
const img = useImage()
const backgroundStyles = computed(() => {
  const imgUrl = img('https://github.com/nuxt.png', { width: 100 })
  return { backgroundImage: `url('${imgUrl}')` }
})


It worked! Sadly, even if we create a composable like useBg where we pass a url as a param, we need to always put const bg = useBg('/images/intro.jpg'); in the 